# Angular: how separately show another component

Tags: angular

I have propably very basic question, but can't find solution. I'm building small app in Angular. I have first component that is login screen. After successfull login I want to show user a table with some data.

I create another component "table", that have this data. Before I made connection between login and showing data, I want just work on style of table. And... I don't know how to entry only to this view.

I mean, when I run http://localhost:4200/ - I see my login screen. But when I try reach http://localhost:4200/table I still... see login screen.

I added in app.module.ts routing:

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'table', component: TableComponent },
];
```

and

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'table', component: TableComponent},
]),
```

I know, that I need later do redirect from login screen to this, but at this point I don't know how to reach this component view. Could someone advise me and explain, because I'm sure I don't see and understand something here.

Comment: Please share your full route configuration: where is login defined? Is there a guard maybe?

Comment: At the moment it's just view and I'm working on styles first. https://pastebin.com/aTueLFUc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as @pertrai1 suggested, do include

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The above code shall be present in the **app.component.html** file.

Next, I would prefer to create separate components for Login and Table. So when finally you authenticate user from your login page, you would be able to redirect them to table page. Below is a sample routes config:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'table', component: TableComponent },
  { path: 'notfound', component: NotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound' },
];
```

To explain the above (assuming you are running this on local),

1. '' would point to localhost:4200 and be default you will see **LoginComponent**
2. 'table' would point towards the **TableComponent**
3. And '**' is optional if you reach a dead end page, you can show a 404 or **NotFoundComponent**

Comment: Amazing - thanks for explaining. I get, whas I miss - I was putting in app.component two things at same time!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` placed in your app somewhere?

Comment: Yes in index.html, just below <app-root></app-root>. I started to think, that maybe if I delete app-root from index.html, and create new component for login and AppComponent end without any content, it will work....?

Comment: And this is problem, because without /table route I see my login screen, but when I add route I see login screen and table content below.